# DNN 9.1.1 - Persona Bar Jquery Errors post update

Tags: jquery, iis-7, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-9

I've recently completed updating a DNN 7.4.1 install to DNN 9.1.1 with some difficulties.

The steps I've followed were to 1st disable all scheduler tasks in the database directly as without that i was getting timeout issues.

Next I upgraded to DNN8 which went through fine after disabling scheduled tasks.
Then I proceeded to update to DNN 9.1.1 which also completed successfully.

Post upgrade I've logged into my website and can see the Persona Bar, but none of the links/functions work. I can see the bar and hover to see the pop-ups and sub pages but clicking on anything results in the following error when viewing in chrome inspector.

I've looked on dnnsoftware.com and google for any similar problems but have only found 1 issue that sounds similar on dnntracker but don't see any patches/fix instructions there.

Article here: https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-9054

My errors are:

```
jquery.js?cdv=136:4 POST http://example.com/API/personaBar/UserSettings/UpdateUserSettings 500 (Internal Server Error)
send    @   jquery.js?cdv=136:4
ajax    @   jquery.js?cdv=136:4
rawCall @   sf.js?cdv=136:89
call    @   sf.js?cdv=136:100
postsilence @   sf.js?cdv=136:112
save    @   persistent.js?cdv=136:29
handleLoadPanel @   main.js?cdv=136:281
handleClickOnHoverMenuItem  @   main.js?cdv=136:666
dispatch    @   jquery.js?cdv=136:3
r.handle    @   jquery.js?cdv=136:3
```

Can this be related to some IIS setting that needs updating for GET/POST methods? Running IIS7, although I do have other DNN9 sites functioning fine on the same server, only they were fresh installs.

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem on an existing website that has been running on 9.0.0 for months.

Comment: @Mickers yes, i was never able to get a fix for this problem i had to recreate the website on a fresh install of 9.1.1. I have a post regarding this over on DNNsoftware.com as well but theres been no input from anyone on this yet. If i get anything back i'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Folks,

I am very late in responding to this question.  But when I encountered this a while ago, I believe I was able to fix by comparing the following tables in my upgraded version:

- PersonaBarMenuDefaultPermissions
- PersonaBarMenuPermission
- PersonaBarPermission

with the tables of a *New* DNN 9.1 install.  Once I inserted the missing permission records and restarted the application, my menu options were fixed in my upgraded environment.  Let me know if you have any questions.